# Are there any ways to fix Log4j vulnerability when it is being used as a transitive dependency

Tags: java, security, log4j, transitive-dependency, mobicents-sip-servlets

My project has a transitive dependency on log4j v1.2.16 through [org.mobicents.servlet.sip](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mobicents.servlet.sip) package used in my project as a direct dependency.

But [org.mobicents.servlet.sip](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mobicents.servlet.sip) is no longer actively developed.

Are there any options to fix this vulnerability other than waiting for [org.mobicents.servlet.sip](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mobicents.servlet.sip) to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution was to explode the log4j-1.2.17.jar, remove the affected classes `SocketServer.class` and `JMSAppender.class`, create a custom jar and use it.

Commands used to explode and create new jar was taken from below stackoverflow answer

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16806235/8864570

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the [log4j-1.2-api bridge](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.0/log4j-1.2-api/index.html). To do this

1. exclude dependency towards log4j 1.x (mind the different groupid, which has changed between 1.x and 2.x)

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mobicents.servlet.sip</groupId>
    <artifactId>sip-servlets-spec</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId><artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
```

2. add dependency towards log4j 2.17.1, with the bridge

```xml
<dependency><groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId><artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId><version>2.17.1</version></dependency>
<dependency><groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId><artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId><version>2.17.1</version></dependency>
<dependency><groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId><artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId><version>2.17.1</version></dependency>
```

Comment: Looks like `sip-servlets-spec` does some programmatic configurations on legacy log4j, tried this and doesn't seem to work. Thanks.